# Brother DCP9015CDW scanner - no ideas

Tags: scanner, sane, brother

Does anyone know how to make this scanner work with Linux? I can print using it - connected with USB, but no scan program can see its SANE drive, even when fully on (not in standby).

Comment: Have you downloaded the Linux firmware from Brother? http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=dcp9015cdw_eu

Comment: If you can't find a driver for it from the manufacturer [VueScan](https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/brother_dcp_9015cdw.html) does support it.  It's commercial, but in my opinion it's by far the best scanning program available.

Comment: @ Yes. I have brscan3 and bscan4. I've put the sane libraries in the same directory as all the other sane libraries: /usr/lib/sane/. I've updated /etc/sane.d/dll.conf with a line reading "brother3". I've also tried in the past with a line reading "brother4". I wake up the printer and try scanimage -L which after a very, very long wait (17 minutes) gives "No scanners were identified."

Comment: @Sato. I've tried VueScan. It looks interesting. I doesn't detect my printer/scanner, either. Given that it works as a printer, I'm wondering if it's faulty.

Comment: Did you run `brsaneconfig4`?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/a/925792/413683

Answer (score 0):

Brother provides drivers for this device. A simple search on their support site gave:
http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=nl&lang=nl&prod=dcp9015cdw_eu&os=128&flang=English
which shows .deb and .rpms.

Comment: I fully aware of this since this is exactly where I got the drivers. This does not even come remotely near answering the question.

Comment: "Does anyone know how to make this scanner work with Linux?" In general, the Brother drivers work. Your question is so short on information that I could not deduce that you had downloaded the drivers.  Did you, by any chance, also run scanimage in debug-mode? Did you look at syslog messages? Does the scanner show-up in `lsusb`? What did `sane-find-scanner` say? and `scanimage -L`?  No information. Only a question: "it doesn't work". So don't be surprised that you get an answer that tells you to download the drivers.